# JOIN Two tables in SQL with one to many mapping and do not join for an Id if any one of the row does not statisfy the condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to join 2 tables with one to many mapping. I have to select the rows for an Id of all rows satisfy the condition or else do not select it.

Example:

```
Table A 
Id Company_Name
 1 ABC 
 2 DEF 
 3 GHI
 4 JKL
```

---

```
TABLE B
ID REGION   BRANCH Number
1 ASIA      1
1 AMERICA   1
1 AUSTRALIA 2
2 ASIA.     1
2 AFRICA.   2
3 ASIA.     3
3 AMERICA.  3
4.ASIA.     1
4. ASIA.    2
4 ASIA.     3
```

Here I want to join table A and table B only when the company of present in both asia and America only.

Output:

```
ID company_name region branch_number
3. GHI Asia  3
3. GHI America. 3
4. JKL ASIA.  1
4. JKL ASIA.  2
4. JKL ASIA.  3
```

- It should not select ID 1 since it is also present in Australia.
- It should also not select 2 as it is not present in America.
- It selects 3 as ASIA and AMERICA is present.
- IT selects 4 AS ASIA is present.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; subquery calculates whether certain `ID` has any rows for regions not begin Asia and America (for them, `sumreg` value is larger than `0` so you omit them from the final result).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  a (id, company_name) as
  3    (select 1, 'abc' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'def' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'ghi' from dual union all
  6     select 4, 'jkl' from dual
  7    ),
  8  b (id, region, branch) as
  9    (select 1, 'asia'     , 1 from dual union all
 10     select 1, 'america'  , 1 from dual union all
 11     select 1, 'australia', 2 from dual union all
 12     select 2, 'asia'     , 1 from dual union all
 13     select 2, 'africa'   , 2 from dual union all
 14     select 3, 'asia'     , 3 from dual union all
 15     select 3, 'america'  , 3 from dual union all
 16     select 4, 'asia'     , 1 from dual union all
 17     select 4, 'asia'     , 2 from dual union all
 18     select 4, 'asia'     , 3 from dual
 19    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 20  select b.id, a.company_name, b.region, b.branch
 21  from a join b on a.id = b.id
 22         join -- the C subquery returns only IDs that are valid only for Asia and America
 23              (select x.id,
 24                      sum(case when x.region not in ('asia', 'america') then 1 else 0 end) sumreg
 25               from b x
 26               group by x.id
 27              ) c on c.id = b.id and c.sumreg = 0;

        ID COM REGION        BRANCH
---------- --- --------- ----------
         3 ghi america            3
         3 ghi asia               3
         4 jkl asia               3
         4 jkl asia               2
         4 jkl asia               1

SQL>
```

Comment: In my case the possibility of other regions is more. This was just the sample data. There can be many regions other than America and Asia. Would it be ok to check not in having performance in mind?

Comment: Just add those regions into NOT IN (line #24).